Springboot Application startup Failed
I have a springboot app and its builds fine, but when I am trying to run it as springboot app in STS its giving the following error... I am not sure what is happening.
Here is the pom.xml I am using
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.ge.aviation.det</groupId>
<artifactId>spcsa-scenario-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0.218</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>spcsa-scenario-service</name>
<description>SPCSA Scenario management services</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <build.number>SNAPSHOT</build.number>
    <aws.sdk.version>1.11.710</aws.sdk.version>   
</properties>

And this the main class:
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * This is the main class of scenario services
 *
 * @author 385220
 */
//@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.ge.aviation.det")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.ge.aviation.det"})
@ImportResource({"classpath*:META-INF/spring/security-context.xml", "classpath*:META-INF/spring/sfdc-quote-config.xml"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAsync
@RestController
public class DetQuoteServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DetQuoteServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public HealthIndicator quoteHealthIndicator() {
        return () -> Health.up().withDetail("spcsa-quote-service", "up").build();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/check", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getCheckStatus() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("success", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

And the error when I run it as an app in local
Error:
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v1.3.3.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2024-10-29 14:46:48.132[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m93476[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.g.a.det.DetQuoteServiceApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting DetQuoteServiceApplication on G2B3G9Y3E with PID 93476 (C:\Users\502622018\cpq-workspace\spcsa-quote-service\target\classes started by 502622018 in C:\Users\502622018\cpq-workspace\spcsa-quote-service)
[2m2024-10-29 14:46:48.135[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m93476[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.g.a.det.DetQuoteServiceApplication    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The following profiles are active: local
[2m2024-10-29 14:46:48.168[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m93476[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2e4b8173: startup date [Tue Oct 29 14:46:48 EDT 2024]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2024-10-29 14:46:49.369[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m93476[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application startup failed

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:888) ~[na:1.8.0_371]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:421) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ge.aviation.det.DetQuoteServiceApplication.main(DetQuoteServiceApplication.java:34) [classes/:na]

[2m2024-10-29 14:46:49.370[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m93476[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application failed to start with classpath: 

The Stacktrace catching the checkCoModification Exception
spcsa-quote-service - DetQuoteServiceApplication [Spring Boot App]  
    com.ge.aviation.det.DetQuoteServiceApplication at localhost:61216   
        Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ConcurrentModificationException))   
            owns: Object  (id=41)   
            LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification() line: 966 [local variables unavailable] 
            LinkedList$ListItr.next() line: 888 [local variables unavailable]   
            ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors() line: 421 
            ConfigurationClassParser.parse(Set<BeanDefinitionHolder>) line: 175 
            ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(BeanDefinitionRegistry) line: 306  
            ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry) line: 239 
            PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(Collection<BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor>, BeanDefinitionRegistry) line: 254 
            PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, List<BeanFactoryPostProcessor>) line: 94 
            AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) line: 606    
            AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(AbstractApplicationContext).refresh() line: 462   
            AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext).refresh() line: 118    
            SpringApplication.refresh(ApplicationContext) line: 766 
            SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplicationRunListeners, ApplicationArguments) line: 361    
            SpringApplication.run(String...) line: 307  
            SpringApplication.run(Object[], String[]) line: 1191    
            SpringApplication.run(Object, String...) line: 1180 
            DetQuoteServiceApplication.main(String[]) line: 36  
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1.8\bin\javaw.exe (Oct 29, 2024, 10:02:16 PM) [pid: 26548]    


Spring Boot 1.3.3 is designed to run with a Java 7 environment; apart from the suggestion to try to switch to a more recent version of the framework, have you tried to compile using a JDK 7 and run the application on that environment? Because from logs it appears you are using a 1.8.0_371.

@FrancescoPoli Spring Boot 1.3.3 recommends to use Java 8 (Source), so this is not the issue.

From the stacktrace, I can deduct that you're using Spring 4.1.0 (due to spring-context-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar). There's two problems with that:

Spring 4.1.x had several issues leading to concurrent modification exceptions (#16613 and #17436). These were solved in Spring 4.1.6.
Spring Boot 1.3.3 is not compatible with Spring 4.1.x and requires at least Spring 4.2.x. (Source). By default, it comes with Spring 4.2.5 (Source).

Since Spring Boot 1.3.3 by default comes with Spring 4.2.5, there's likely a conflicting dependency (or you're overriding the version by yourself). The easiest way to investigate this is by checking the dependency tree. This can be done using the following command:
mvn dependency:tree

Once you resolve that issue, the ConcurrentModificationException should also disappear.

yeah there was a dependency of that jar in one of the proejct..once I updated the dependency with 4.2.5 this error disappeared

Based on the logs looks like ConcurrentModificationException is  originating from the ConfigurationClassParser.
Try below steps to drill down the actual issue

Ensure that no concurrent modifications are happening in any of your configuration classes.
Given you are using spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE, consider upgrading to a more recent version if possible.
Review your configuration classes to ensure that any @Import or @Configuration annotations are not causing concurrent modifications.
If you have any custom configuration, ensure that no collections are being modified while they are being iterated over.
If already done above steps, Try to Debug the issue by adding Exception Breakpoint for ConcurrentModificationException



when I debug for the exception..I am getting the error in SpringApplication.run(DetQuoteServiceApplication.class, args); line itself erroring out at run method..can u suggest what is wrong here..or any annotation is mixing up..I have given the whole class

That means there is some configuration class that is trying to modify something in collection. Any code similar to below must be avoided
for (String item : myList) { if (item.equals("two")) { myList.remove(item); // This will cause ConcurrentModificationException } }
